# Track user inactivity even when page closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my frontend to track user inactivity (no mouse/keyboard input) and call my logout API when a specified time threshold is reached.

It seems straightforward at first (promising libraries like [jquery-idletimer](https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer)), however the inactivity tracking needs to support multiple tabs of the same website and even when the user closes all tabs of the website. The duration they have exited the page should count towards the threshold, and if reached while page is closed, my logout API needs to still be called. If the user reopens the page before the threshold, the timer needs to be reset.

Is this still possible from the frontend?

Comment: If user exits the page, the JS goes in the bin. Even when running in the background, most modern browsers limit what can be done. You may have better luck setting a token/cookie and when the app starts or resumes do a token verification against potentially invalidated tokens in the backend.

Comment: @DrewReese I already use a session ID cookie that checks the backend. It currently supports hard expiry (a time column that's set a static duration from session creation).

How would I support user inactivity? I was thinking each time a request is made with a session, refresh another time column for inactivity expiry. However this measures activity by requests made, instead of mouse/keyboard input. I see a potential problem where the frontend may continue to make requests in the background without user action, so it doesn't actually represent user activity.